# Convert dataframe to quarter

Tags: python

I have a dataframe (df). The Date variable is a string. I want to convert it to date and reformat it to the date at the end of the quarter. A sample is below:

```
df:
         Date
0     201601
1     201602
2     201603
3     201604
```

`201601` is the first quarter of 2016 and `201604` is the fourth quarter of 2016. The desired outcome is:

```
df:
          Date
0     2016-03-31
1     2016-06-30
2     2016-09-30
3     2016-12-31
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format = '%Y%q')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function to compute the date and then apply that function.

Using the monthrange function from the calendar module (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange), your function might look something like:

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import datetime   

def end_quarter(quarter):
    year = int(quarter[:4])
    month = int(quarter[-2:]) * 3
    day = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    return datetime(year, month, day).date()
```

and you could then apply it using:

```
df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(end_quarter)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep treating it as a string, and simply do an if / else statement, i.e.

```
res = []
for i in df['Date']:
    v1 = i[-2:]
    if v1 == '01':
        res.append(i[:4] + '-03-31')
    elif v1 == '02':
        res.append(i[:4] + '-06-30')
    elif v1 == '03':
        res.append(i[4:] + '-09-30')
    else:
        res.append(i[4:] + '-12-31')

#>>> res
#['2016-03-31', '2016-06-30', '03-09-30', '04-12-31']
```